# Rails3 - extract common actions in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Having lot of resources that share common custom actions, ie: import and export:

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      post "import"
      get "export"
    end
  end
  resources :companies do
    collection do
      post "import"
      get "export"
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to extract repeating code and reuse it?
In previous Rails I think that could be achieved with something like this:

```
  imp_exp_collection = {:import => :post, :export => :get}
  resources :users, :collection => imp_exp_collection
  resources :companies, :collection => imp_exp_collection
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can define a method in your routes file and can invoke them like

```
def imp_exp_collection
  collection  do
    post "import"
    get "export"
  end
end
```

and use it as follow

```
  resources :users do
   imp_exp_collection
  end
```

Comment: I knew it should be something simple :) and what if I want to put route definition in some lib?